# How to use Hangfire job queuing for processing requests from ASP.NET HttpHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, queue, hangfire

I'm trying to use `Hangfire` to queue processing of data acquired via a `HttpHandler`.

The Hangfire server is correctly configured and works fine with simple functions like the ones explained [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-in-background.html).

I can't seem to find a way to use my `HttpContext` data to work with Hangfire.

This code works:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
                () => Console.WriteLine("HELLO")
            );
        }
```

This code does not works:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
                () => doServerSideWork(context)
            );
        } 

public void doServerSideWork(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            var jsonString = String.Empty;
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            context.Response.Write(jsonString);
        }
```

I'm getting a `BackgroundJobClientException`:

> {"Self referencing loop detected for property 'Context' with type
>   'System.Web.HttpContext'. Path 'ApplicationInstance'."}

After reading on the subject, it seems like a `HttpContext` can't be serialized, which is the first step in the job management Hangfire do (see previous link).

How can I use Hangfire to treat my HTTP requests ?

Comment: This is never going to work. You can't just pass an HTTP context around on threads like this and expect that you can write back to the Response at the end. Hangfire should not be used for this kind of work. Why aren't you using async/await inside your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: It's impossible

**Longer answer**: It is inherently impossible to serialize an HttpContext and act on it later. If the "background work" you're trying to do is as simple as the code snippet you've shown you should be using async/await to avoid blocking threads and keep your server as responsive as possible. If the background work is actually CPU bound and it's not feasible for you to use async/await you need to extract the data from the HttpContext that is relevant for starting your work and pass that instead. In this case you should return a response to the client immediately, providing them with a callback address where they can either poll for updates or be notified in realtime with something like a websocket when the job completes.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the purpose of my app will be to synchronize a client database with a server database. I want to implement a queue process because I dont want multiple parallel synchronisation processes. It needs to be running only one synchronisation process at a time.

Comment: np, I'm glad that it helped